# Select .NET or .NET Core on Azure with a ASP.NET Core website

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I'm hosting a range of websites on Azure. Some ASP.NET MVC and others ASP.NET Core. I noticed that there is a *Stack* setting beneath *General settings* with the values `.NET` and `.NET Core`:

[image: Stack]

For some of my ASP.NET Core websites, the value `.NET` is selected. Typically the ones that I migrated to ASP.NET Core and just deployed to an existing website previously running ASP.NET MVC. My question here is, what does this setting do? And why doesn't it seem to make a difference when deploying a ASP.NET Core website which setting this has?

Answer (score 0):

In App Service Stack settings are used to set type of language and the version you need to use. App Service support in general supports the following languages:

- ASP.NET Core
- Node.js
- PHP
- Python
- Java
- Ruby

and depend on the OS say,

if you create on windows, there are 5 stacks underneath it

1. .NET
2. .NET Core
3. PHP
4. Python
5. Java

If you choose linux, there are 7 stacks can selected on portal

1. Ruby
2. Node
3. PHP
4. .NET Core
5. Java8
6. Java11
7. Python

Here are the details on the [stack settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-language-stack-settings)

Comment: I don't think that answers the question. I have in fact read the documentation. But, if an ASP.NET Core website runs just as fine on .NET. Why are there two options and when to pick what?